# Help me ID book about time traveling kids

Tags: story-identification

Can't remember the name of a book I read as a kid. Premise is that teens travel back in time using some sort of diode. I think the teens were created somehow and one is named "fiver." The "fiver" name referred to the sequence of the traveler. So the protagonist was the fourth traveler, and Fiver would take over after him. The book would've published before the 90s, but I'm not sure how much earlier. Help?

Comment: I see you tried Reddit first ;-) https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/4y03rk/time_travel_book_for_i_think_young_adults/

Comment: AH! Found it by continuing to poke around here. The Danger Quotient.

http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105139/time-travel-young-adult-novel-from-late-80s/105144#105144

Comment: Well done! Since it's already been answered here, I'm going to mark this question as a duplicate, but if you're interested in sci-fi and fantasy, I hope you'll stick around on the site :-)